# Разграничение прав в Mongodb

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

Добрый день. Нужна помощь с монгой v2.4.6

Нужно разграничить доступ к монге, а именно сделать скажем двух
пользователей с полными правами и пользователя с правами только на чтение. Пользователей создаю так:
Создание пользователя с правами "read/write":

> use mydatabase
>   db.addUser("admin", "123456")

Создание пользователя с правами "readonly":

> db.addUser("web", "prettyGoodPass", true)

В итоге я без пользователя могу создавать ключи и коллекции. Как бы всё это разграничить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перезапустите mongodb с опцией `--auth`:

```
mongod --auth --config /etc/mongodb/mongodb.conf
```

и пользователю нужно дать роль "read":

```
db.createUser({ "user" : "user1", "pwd": "password1", "roles" : [ "read" ] })
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Авторизацию проходим. Но пользователь с рид онли может создавать коллекции и ключи.

Comment: Дайте пользователю роль read

Comment: Не помогает. Пользователь всеравно, может создавать коллекции и удалять пользователей. Если что то проверяю я это через утилиту Robomongo.

Comment: подскажите разницу. Запускаю mongodb --auth или можно просто в конфиге указать auth = true. Или нужно чтобы оба значения были. В конфиге и при запуске демона.